# Why doesn't $\omega ^ {\omega}$ have cardinality equal to real numbers?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

One set of order type $2\omega$ is the set {1,2} $\times  N$

One set of order type $3\omega $ is {1,2,3} $\times N$

Similarly, order type $\omega ^2$ would be the set $N \times N$

$\omega ^3$ would be $N\times N \times N$

.

.

.

$\omega ^{\omega}$ would be the never-ending cartesian product $N\times N\times N\times N\times.........$

However, this infinite cartesian product simply corresponds to the set of all infinite sequences of natural numbers, aka the real numbers. Then, doesn't this mean that a set of order type $\omega ^{\omega}$ would have cardinality equal to reals?

Moreover, you could apply the diagonal argument to the set $N\times N\times N\times......$ to directly prove that it's uncountable.

Comment: Who agrees: it is bad to write $\omega$ for $\aleph_0$, except in a certain narrow part of model theory.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm a model theorist, and I also object to the bad habit among logicians of writing $\omega$ when they mean $\aleph_0$!

Comment: @GEdgar To be fair, $\omega$ and $\aleph_0$ are literally the same thing. The real issue is that we use the same notation for ordinal and cardinal arithmetic operations, which means that the context clue provided by ordinal/cardinal *notation* is crucial. That's my main gripe: in particular, in my opinion (and following old notation I quite like) "$2^\omega$" should be unconfusingly countable, and "${}^\omega2$" should be unconfusingly uncountable!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the case of *cardinal arithmetic*, where $\omega^\omega$ is the set of all functions $f\colon\omega\to\omega$, then yes, you are correct. That set has the same cardinality as the real numbers. And indeed, it corresponds to the infinite product of copies of $\omega$ itself.

However, in the case of *ordinal arithmetic*, where $\omega^\omega$ is the supremum of $\omega^n$ for $n<\omega$, there $\omega^\omega$ is countable. To see that, note that what it actually corresponds to is the functions in the infinitary products above which are eventually $0$. So we can identify those with the finite sequences of natural numbers, which is a countable set.

What we see here is an example of continuity of ordinal arithmetic, which is defined to be continuous: limit steps are literally the limit of their previous steps; and cardinal arithmetic, which is defined by taking cardinality of certain sets, and it is very discontinuous, especially when infinite exponentiation is involved.

Comment: This nicely explains where the confusion comes from. There are two ways to interpret $\omega^\omega$ and they have very different meanings.

Comment: Is it not true that $N\times N\times N....$ has ordinality $w^w$ but also has cardinality of the continuum? What is an example of a countable  set of ordinality $w^w$?

Comment: @RyderRude Ordinal exponentiation corresponds to counting functions **with finite support**: $\mathsf{OrdExp}(\alpha,\beta)$ is the ordertype, with respect to the "compare-at-last-point-of-difference" ordering, of the set of functions $f:\beta\rightarrow\alpha$ with $\vert\{\gamma\in\beta:f(\gamma)\not=0\}\vert<\aleph_0$. In particular, $\omega^\omega$ is the ordertype of the set of **cofinitely-often-zero** sequences of natural numbers, with $$f\triangleleft g\quad\iff\quad f(\max\{a: f(a)\not=g(a)\})<g(\max\{a: f(a)\not=g(a)\}).$$ See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358455/).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I've edited your comment. Let me know if it's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

In ordinal exponentiation, $x^\omega$ = sup($x^n$) for natural number n. As such, it is different form cardinal exponentiation.

In The Book of Numbers, by John Conway and Richard Kenneth Guy, there is a bijection from the natural numbers to a set of order type $\omega^\omega$. The bijection is specified by these two rules:

1. If the greatest prime factor of m is greater than the greatest prime factor of n, then m comes later than n.
2. If m/x comes later than n/x, then m comes later than n.

One can verify that this well-order has order type $\omega^\omega$.